# Allowed memory size exhausted in Symfony 3.3

Tags: php, nginx, composer-php, symfony-3.3, fpm

On my production server with the following configuration:

- Nginx
- phpfpm-7.0
- List item

Symfony3.3

I still receive 500 error while targeting home page with the following error in my phpFpm error logs acceding the app.php page:

```
[error] 16800#16800: *9 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in .../vendor/composer/autoload_static.php on line 4248" while reading response header from upstream, client: XXXXXXXX, server: _, request: "GET /app.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "XXXXXXX"
```

I tried to increase the memory_limit param in those locations without any change:

- /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf
- /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini

Do you have any idea where could it come from?

Comment: You can check the used configuration using `phpinfo();` - also, you might need to restart the httpd for changes to take effect.

Comment: @ccKep The configuration file specified by the php -i command is /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini. I tried to restart fpm and nginx each time I did a configuration change but it didn't solved this Allowed memory size issue

Comment: `php -i` might use a different configuration file than your web environment. Try creating a `info.php` file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` as its contents and compare the path (and perhaps memory limits) there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok solved.

My issue was coming from extra configuration which was into /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf file overriding the php.ini conf.

Thank you!

Comment: can you please explain what that configuration was?